# "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package...". Is it possible to install Node.js (v0.10.15) on Windows XP?

Tags: node.js

I want to use Node.js under Windows XP. I've downloaded the `node-v0.10.15-x86.msi` installer but when I try to install Node.js I always get this error at the middle of the process:

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
>   is 2908.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Is it possible to install Node.js on Windows? I cannot find any installation instructions on their site. I have AMD Athlon XP 1833 MHz processor. It is quite old processor. May this be the reason?

Comment: Hey, what for downvote? Is it a bad question? It is a real issue with Node.js installation and a real picture of it. Have a brave to comment your downvote actions.

Answer (score 5):

So, I figured out how to install it :)

I did a double click on `node-v0.10.15-x86.msi` file in order to install Node. And that caused an error.

`.msi` files shouldn't be installed that way. I found a solution on this page http://thebackroomtech.com/2007/08/23/howto-extract-files-from-a-msi-file-using-the-windows-command-line/

So my steps in Windows command line. I pointed a directory where to unpack `node-v0.10.15-x86.msi` to:

```
C:\>msiexec /a "C:\Downloads\Programs\Node.js\node-v0.10.15-x86.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

And now it works. It unpacked Node.js and all its dependencies to `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. I just added the directory to PATH.

I'm glad I can use Node on Windows. Working under Ubuntu is a pain.

Comment: worth noting that you should also add the npm directory to your path `C:\Documents and Settings\YOUR_USERNAME\Application Data\npm` for xp

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For resolve this problem you need to remove this key from registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
Installer\UserData\S-1-5-21-1123561945-1935655697-1060284298-1003\
Components\AD95649F068525549B26938D7D18FEA7
```

Founded [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2007/11/12/windows-installer-error-2908/)

Answer (score 1):

For me the S-1-5-21 was different, I renamed it to _del

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
 \SOFTWARE
 \Microsoft
 \Windows
 \CurrentVersion
 \Installer
 \UserData
 \S-1-5-21-1292428093-1606980848-1188629396-500_del
```